# Could we replace humans in this picture with robots to generate electricity?

Tags: energy, robots, power-sources

My idea is to replace the humans with robots on magnets - like the maglev trains or just a couple smart wheels. Simple mathematical algorithms would adjust the robots to keep the contraption spinning constantly. Another idea along the same lines would be a smart track that simply moves a weight along the circle at the appropriate time.

[Men turning a hamster wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e308u.jpg)

Comment: So ... what's your question exactly? Try adding the image to your actual post and explaining what you're trying to achieve, please.

Comment: The robot walks or drives in the giant hamster wheel, the hamster wheel turns the turbine, the turbine supplies the electric grid, the electric grid powers the robot.  At each stage, there is a loss, and at some point the whole thing winds down.  If you were hoping to get some form of perpetual motion device, sorry, you lose.

Comment: no not perpetual energy. Imagine the robots are powered by solar charged batteries, and require very little energy to navigate the hamster wheels in order to keep the contraption moving. This is not a perpetual energy device at all.

Comment: The link to the image is there:

Comment: http://imgur.com/aPFygh2

Comment: Why not just have the solar panels power the device?

Comment: Yes, just use the energy from the solar panels.  If you are just trying to generate electricity, as your title says, the whole robot contraption would just add unnecessary loss.  Now, if you need the circular motion for something else, like grinding grain or pumping water, a humanoid robot pushing a wheel is not terribly efficient, but I could conceive cultural/historical reasons for a world to evolve to that point.

Comment: The idea comes down to utilizing gravity as an energy source. If the robots are strategically adjusted at exactly the right times the contraption would continue to spin - without need for wind as an example. It's simply adjusting the balance of the apparatus so that it continues to fall - using gravity and its own motion to spin. Just like the humans do but with precise and efficient robotic adjustments.

Comment: what you are hinting at **is** a perpetual motion machine.  It simply is not possible for them to generate more power that way than they would consume.  Conservation of energy and entropy are inescapable facts of life.

Comment: I see your point however you are discounting the energy that gravity is contributing to the equation. The robots do not push the contraption downward - it is in a constant state of falling. All they are doing is moving slightly to the most optimum position so that the falling continues and thus, the contraption continues to spin along.

Comment: @user2708841 Any energy that the mechanism gets from moving mass to the bottom is $mgh$, however when moving that mass back up to the top of the wheel you **lose** the same amount of energy: $mg(-h)$. If what you are saying were possible, you *could* create a perpetual motion machine. As it is, a spinning wheel doesn't get energy from gravity.

Comment: gravity would not contribute anything to the equation.  the potential energy (energy from gravity) exchanged to kinetic energy when any part of the contraption is going down is then exchanged right back to potential energy when that same part of the contraption has to go back up to the starting point.  And you would lose some of it to friction in the wheel bearings and wind resistance.  Wish it were that easy to generate electricity.  If the output was more than what the robots consume, all you would have to do is use some of the output to power the robots and you'd have perpetual motion.

Comment: I am wondering if you are a young person (don't answer that).  The thing is, I would not want to discourage you.  If you are, this sort of thinking - "what if..." is exactly the sort of thinking that will make a good scientist, and as you learn more about physics, you will learn about some of what has already been figured out as "won't work", but hopefully you will retain that "what if..." mentality that is so crucial for an innovator in science or any field.

Comment: to clarify - gravity simply makes the robot's job easier. All they need to do is adjust their position within the circle slightly at the right moment to maximize the rotational motion of the spinning contraption. Just like the humans due by taking a step or two forward or backward. Very little energy is required to keep it moving - just slight movements - nothing monumental here. Two 110 llb chinese guys can make a 1 ton contraption spin quite fast and quite easily. It's just slight weight adjustments and letting gravity to the "work" for you.

Comment: The only total energy that 1 ton contraption has, when spinning, is the energy added by the two chinese guys (minus frictional losses).  They in turn had to get that energy from somewhere (eating).  Gravity does not add anything to it.  It looks like gravity is adding, because at the bottom the thing is moving so hard and fast, but that same part that goes to the bottom moving so hard and fast, comes back up to the top moving not even as hard and fast as the little chinese guy pushed it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the intelligent, non-rude or condescending discussion. Much appreciated!

Comment: Yes. Gravity does not help the wheel spin. The gain that you get by gravity pulling the falling side down is simultaneously lost in moving the rising side up. If there was no air resistance or friction or other outside forces, then once you got the wheel spinning it would continue to spin forever, because the energy required to move the rising side up would be exactly equal to the energy gained from the falling side coming down. But in real life, there is friction etc. If the wheel is very well balanced and well oiled, it may not take MUCH energy to keep it spinning. But >0.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, but...

Although it would be possible to generate power this way (using humans, hamsters, or robots), it will always require a higher energy input than it can output.

Furthermore, you often get much better efficiencies by removing intermediate steps.  As the comments mentioned, you get better results if you go straight from PV panels to electrical power by removing the hamster wheel and hamster (robot).

[This resource describes the laws of thermodynamics](http://physicsforidiots.com/physics/thermodynamics/)

> #### Zeroth law of thermodynamics
>
> – If two thermodynamic systems
>   are each in thermal equilibrium with a third, then they are in thermal
>   equilibrium with each other.
>
> #### First law of thermodynamics
>
> – Energy can neither be created
>   nor destroyed. It can only change forms. In any process, the total
>   energy of the universe remains the same. For a thermodynamic cycle the
>   net heat supplied to the system equals the net work done by the
>   system.
>
> #### Second law of thermodynamics
>
> – The entropy of an isolated
>   system not in equilibrium will tend to increase over time, approaching
>   a maximum value at equilibrium.
>
> #### Third law of thermodynamics
>
> – As temperature approaches
>   absolute zero, the entropy of a system approaches a constant minimum.

Of all the laws in science, this set of laws is probably the most inviolate of them all.  If we ever find that these laws can be broken, then most of our understanding of how the Universe works is very broken.  Basically you must throw out almost all theories and engineering design.

A humorous lay persons version of these laws is:

1. You can't win
2. You can't break-even
3. You can't quit the game

Comment: I thought the First Law of Thermodynamics was, "You don't talk about thermodynamics." :-)